# Android download image randomly fail

Tags: android, bitmap, android-asynctask

I think my error log will describe my question clearly.

I am doing few of image download in a product showcase using Async . But when come to download (larger maybe) image the app forced close , **Note: some other product are properly download and display without problem.**

Here is some of my code in asynctask , i executed **DownloadImage(URL)** in **doInBackground** and store it in a **bitmapArray**

```
private Bitmap DownloadImage(String URL) {
Bitmap bitmap = null;
InputStream in = null;
try {
    in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(in, 32 * 4096);

    ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(50);
    int current = 0;
    while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
    baf.append((byte) current);
    }
    byte[] imageData = baf.toByteArray();
    bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData,0,imageData.length);


    in.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

Log.txt

```
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #3
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeByteArray(Native Method)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:426)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(BitmapFactory.java:444)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at com.nazartt.angtrading.ShowCase$task.DownloadImage(ShowCase.java:201)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at com.nazartt.angtrading.ShowCase$task.doInBackground(ShowCase.java:129)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at com.nazartt.angtrading.ShowCase$task.doInBackground(ShowCase.java:1)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
02-21 06:54:35.982: E/AndroidRuntime(2026):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
```

Comment: I am sure this sentence `BufferedInputStream(in, 32 * 4096);` causes a problem

Comment: I'm sorry i just used some tutorial code , what should i do now? i tried put smaller or bigger number but its still dont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are downloading multiple images then you should use some **Caching** algorithm like given below, there way you would be able to cache images and load it from cache easily.

1. [Lazy list by Fedor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3068012/379693)
2. [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader)
3. [ImageLoader by Novoda](https://github.com/novoda/ImageLoader)